# What's the typical way to tie in OOP PHP with a MySQLi object?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I've been using PHP procedurally for years, but I've decided to really get with the times and start practicing OOP.

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db);

class user {
      public $username;
      public function __construct($ID) {
             $sql_query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`='$ID'";
             // execute that query somehow, store result in $result.
             $this->username = $result;
      }
}

$some_user = new user(1);
```

(I know that query needs to be escaped etc, I'm just trying to give a basic example)

My main question is **what's the best way to interact with the `$db` object within a class**? I would call `$db->query($sql_query);` but `$db` is not accessible. A lot of Googling hasn't given me a solid answer, but I've seen a lot of suggestions to pass in the `$db` object into the constructer, like:

```
 $some_user = new user(1, $db);
```

Am I right in understanding this as "Data Injection"? It seems like there must be a better way than to explicitly include it in every single constructor. Of course I could always *create* $db within each class but repeatedly connecting to the database also seems unnecessary.

Comment: It's called dependency injection, and yes, it (or a variation thereupon) is almost certainly the way to go.

Comment: You might look up some design patterns that are commonly used to solve your "problem": active record, data mapper, row/table gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this seems to happen in the global scope, so $db isn't accessible in class user yet    
$db = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db);

class user {
  public $username;
  //to make global $db accessible, pass a reference to user's constructor:
  public function __construct($ID,&$db) {
         $sql_query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`='$ID'";
         // execute that query somehow, store result in $result
         // if you exec the query, first you get a mysqli result *OBJECT*: 
         $result_obj = $db -> query($sql_query);
         // next you pull out the row out of this object as an associative array:
         $row = $result_obj -> fetch_assoc(); 
         //finally you assign the retrieved value as a property of your user:            
         $this->username = $row['username'];
  }
}
//be careful NOT to pass a reference here!!
$some_user = new user(1,$db); // NO ampersand here! passing by ref is deprecated!
```